# Walker whose Velocity is a Brownian Bridge

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, random-walks, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a continuous random walk $x (t) $, in which the velocity $v (t) = \mathrm dx/\mathrm dt $ rather than the position is described by Brownian motion, so that $v (t) = B_t $ where $B_{t+\epsilon} - B_t \sim \mathcal N (0,\epsilon^2) $. Given the initial position $x (0) = x_0$ and velocity $v (0) = v_0$, the distribution of position with time is nevertheless normally distributed, namely $x (T) \sim \mathcal N (x_0 + v_0T, T^3/3) $.

Suppose that at time $t=T$, the walker is known to have a particular velocity $v_T $, fixing a final boundary condition as well as an initial one. What then is the distribution of $x (T) $, and how does one approach the analysis?

(This question is a follow-up to [a question I asked earlier about a random walk with speed boosts](https://mathoverflow.net/q/290289/3723). As this sort of question appears easier to approach in a continuous time setting, that is the context I take in this case.)

Comment: Conditioning BM to have a fixed value $v_T$ at time $T$ leads to the *Brownian bridge*. You need to integrate it: the result is again normally distributed, with mean $x_0 + (v_0 + v_T)/2$ and appropriate variance.

Answer (score 6):

As Kwaśnicki remarked, the velocity process $v_t$ is a *Brownian bridge*, which can be represented as:  $$
v_t = v_0 (1 - \frac{t}{T}) + v_T \frac{t}{T} + (T - t) \int_0^t \frac{1}{T-s} d B_s \;.
$$ (For an intro to this representation, see the first exercise of the following [exercise sheet on Brownian bridges](http://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Karl-Theodor_Sturm/Lectures/vorlesungSS09/sheet01.SS09.pdf)).

As before, the position process $x_T$ is obtained by integrating the velocity process: \begin{align*}
x_T &= x_0 + \int_0^T v_t dt  \\
&=x_0 + \frac{T}{2} (v_0 + v_T) + \int_0^T \int_0^t   \frac{T-t}{T-s} d B_s dt \\ 
&=x_0 + \frac{T}{2} (v_0 + v_T) + \int_0^T \left( \int_s^T   \frac{T-t}{T-s} dt \right) d B_s 
\end{align*}
This double integral is Gaussian with mean zero and variance $T^3 / 12$.  Hence, $$
x_T \sim \mathcal{N}( x_0 + \frac{T}{2} (v_0 + v_T), \frac{T^3}{12} ) \;.
$$
Note that the variance of this process with pinned initial and final velocities is a quarter of the variance of the position process with pinned initial and unpinned final velocity -- which makes sense intuitively.

Comment: Belated thanks! I appreciate the link to the exercise sheet. But is there perhaps a set of lecture notes (in English) for the material which would've me the background information to carry out such an exercise myself --- assuming of course that you prefer not to point to an actual derivation which I could use as a bibliographical reference? (Have pity on a poor computer scientist!)

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Here are some online resources: (i) page 10 of http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matloujh/ma4265/ito-3.pdf,  (ii) https://books.google.com/books?id=FUJGDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=%22Brownian+Bridge+sde%22&source=bl&ots=70C5RvaG-M&sig=_vsNhQO_rOAX4Qc60ik1oJeRFJE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigo_yT5e7YAhXxguAKHbbuB2IQ6AEIQTAD#v=onepage&q=%22Brownian%20Bridge%20sde%22&f=false, (iii) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115727/brownian-bridge-expression-for-a-brownian-motion?rq=1 , (iv) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408620/brownian-bridge?rq=1, and ...

Comment: ...  (v) https://books.google.com/books?id=JYzW0uqQxB0C&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=%22sde+for+Brownian+Bridge%22&source=bl&ots=StqLbfZ1Y4&sig=YOJtTncezCVSV9zvGguE2v_JStk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih47j25e7YAhVkkeAKHVQTAr8Q6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Brownian%20Bridge%22&f=false